# Windows 8.1 Swing (Java) applications text rendering

Tags: windows-8.1, java, rendering, swing

The other day, I searched for a free UML editor tool, and as it turns out the best of them are implemented using the popular Swing framework, in Java. As it turns out, Windows 8.1 has some serious problems with text rendering for Swing applications. Let me show a few examples:

[image: TinyUML]

[image: TinyUML 2]

In a different Swing application:

[image: VioletUML]

[image: VioletUML 2]

The labels on almost everything look like, this, they keep flickering, and randomly disappearing partially. I never experienced something like this on any other Windows version.

Is this a common problem? If so, is there a way to fix this, without me, having access to the source of these applications?

**I'm using:**

- Lenovo G500s notebook
- Windows 8.1 (64 bit)
- I have both JDK and JRE1.7 installed.

**If I'm posting, this question on the bad Stack exchange site, please advise, where to ask it!**

Comment: You did say Java, that's a feature of using Java, write once debug everywhere and hope it sorta works...

Comment: Debug everywhere :D I will quote you on that.

Comment: use -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false in vm args.
source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737535/swing-rendering-appears-broken-in-jdk-1-8-correct-in-jdk-1-7

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with java 8 and not windows 8.1. I had the same issue on different operating systems which had multiple graphic rendering chips and java 8 installed (i mean hardware systems with onboard graphic chip e.g. intel hd, and normal graphic chip e.g. nvidia)

just fall back to java 7 and this issue will be resolved

EDIT.: or start your java application explicit with the normal graphic chip